# Bootloader, uefi, bios documentation

Tags: bios, uefi, bootloader

I'm facing incredibly annoying issues with installing kali 2 (not booting + completely messing windows 7 boot) in uefi mode.
I went trough alot of topics and solutions and nothing seems to work, everything is a real waste of time since you cannot understand anything from the proposed solution - since no one explains why that should work.
At this point I wouldn't mind if I would have to become an expert in the way OS are booted, just to be able to fix manualy an issue of this kind. The only problem is that I can't find any documentation, any looow level way to control it... only solutions that might work for some exact case.
Are you aware of any documentation that might help really understanding the matter? How UEFI works, how it worked before it, how you can control it, etc?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general background information on EFI, especially as it relates to Ubuntu and other Linux distributions, I recommend reading:

- The [UEFI specification (version 2.5).](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%202_5.pdf) This describes UEFI in highly technical language. It's most likely to be useful if you want to do EFI programming or otherwise tinker on EFI's "guts." It will be of little or no use if you're an ordinary user who just wants to install an OS.
- Adam Williamson's [blog post on how EFI works.](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) This covers the basic principles behind EFI pretty well, and provides some tips that are likely to be useful for EFI novices.
- My own [Linux on UEFI: A Quick Installation Guide.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) This document is less theoretical and more practical than Adam Williamson's blog post, but it still provides some background information.
- My own [EFI Boot Loaders for Linux.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html) This is a series of pages that describes several EFI boot loaders, as well as general information, generic installation instructions, advice on using Secure Boot, and so on.
- The Ubuntu community wiki's [page on UEFI.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) This is a bit disorganized and poorly written in places, but it's helpful to users of Ubuntu and related distributions who want to install in EFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

regarding your curiosity about how things work, i am not quite clear until the deep details, but the thing about eufi is that concerning about ubuntu you need to use uefi mode, and when you do it, you need to disable the secure boot. Maybe this article will help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI.

secondly, about your messing up with windows bootloader, you need to go to ubuntu terminal [live boot using USB or CD], and do some of these commands:

1. sudo os-prober -> it will let you to detect OSes in your system, in case if there is dual boot inside of it.
2. sudo update-grub -> it will let you update with the current system, and fix the grub, hopefully it will open up bootloader menu, to choose your OSes after you restart.
3. restart it.

Comment: Ubuntu supports Secure Boot "out of the box," and has for quite some time. That said, there are occasional problems because of bugs in certain programs and in specific EFI implementations or because people don't follow directions.

Comment: i think to be honest, if thats the case, the last solution is reinstall it. So you went to the boot configuration, and where did you see that warning tho?